# Check to see if array of strings contains a substring value in react

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of values and I'm looking to filter through the array to find usernames that contain the search query.

The search query is taken as an input from the user.

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    let result;
    if (usernames != null) {
      result = usernames.filter((user) => user.username.includes(query));
    }
    console.log(result?.pop()?.username);
  }, [query]);
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Issues

1. The `usernames` array is an array of objects with the value string you want to search in nested in a `link` property.
2. Array.prototype.map returns an array the same length as the starting array and isn't for issuing side-effect.

## Solution

Check for the substring from the `link` property, and use `array.prototype.find` or `array.prototype.filter` to search for matches. `find` returns the first match or undefined if not found, `filter` returns all matches in an array.

```
usernames.find((user) => user.link.includes("gl"));
usernames.filter((user) => user.link.includes("gl"));
```

Code:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  let result;

  if (usernames != null) {
    result = usernames.find((user) => user.link.includes("gl"));
  }

  console.log(result);
}, []);
```

```js
const usernames = [
  { link: "apple" },
  { link: "google" },
  { link: "shopify" }
];

let result;

if (usernames != null) {
  result = usernames.find((user) => user.link.includes("gl"));
}

console.log(result?.link);
```

Note: array.prototype.find returns `undefined` if the value is not found, so you'll likely want to check for nullish values before doing anything with the result, like access the `link` property, i.e. trying `result.link` to display "google".

Note 2: If you use `filter` then the `result` will be an array. You can either iterate the array, or `pop` the last value (or `unshift` the 0th element) to get a single result object. You'll still need to do the null check, something like `result?.[0]?.username`.

Comment: Hi Drew! This is exactly what i need. However, I couldn't get it to work in my code. I updated the question with my actual code and also an image of how the queried data from firebase is being stored (I'm storing it in a variable called "username"). Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @RogerStaxx No worries. If you use `filter` then the `result` will be an array. You can either iterate the array, or `pop` the last value (or `unshift` the 0th element) to get a single result object. You'll still need to do the null check, something like `result?.[0]?.username`.

Comment: Gotcha! How do I pop the last value? As expected, it's only returning one of the values.

Comment: @RogerStaxx `result?.pop()?.username` should work.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. I just updated the code so you can see it.

Comment: In other words, I have usernames "Laurie" and "Lizzy" and only Lizzy is returning

Comment: @RogerStaxx The `let result;` is only in scope inside the `if` block, it's not the same one outside the block in the console log. Move `let result;` *outside* the `if` scope, or move the console log *into* the same scope. I also don't see a "Laurie" in your data. You may also want to do a case-insensitive search.

Comment: Still seems to be returning one value (I'm such a newbie ). I just updated the code again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226071/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-roger-staxx).

Answer (score 1):

I can't be certain as to the full context of what you're doing, but generally speaking, to find an element in an array of objects that matches a specific condition, you need something like this:

```js
const query = 'gl'

const ar = [{link: "apple"},
    {link: "google"},
    {link: "shopify"}]

const result = ar.find(item => item.link.includes(query))
if(result)
    console.log(result.link)
else
    console.log('Query not found')
```

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 issue on your code:

1 - in your map, user is not a string but an object containing a string named link
so if you want to check if your link contains "gl" you have to replace

```
user.includes("gl")
```

by

```
user.link.includes("gl")
```

2 - The map doesn't look like it's the best option for your need.
You should take a look at this [interesting article](https://medium.com/poka-techblog/simplify-your-javascript-use-map-reduce-and-filter-bd02c593cc2d)

I think the filter function is more adapted in this situation.

If you want to get an array containing only the objects with a link including "gl" you need:

```
usernames.filter((user) => user.includes("gl"));
```